# Non-looping Animated Gif won't replay on web page reload

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an animated gif that only plays once in Fireworks.

I've placed it on the webpage: http://www.mediaworks.co.uk/content-marketing/hollywood-survival/index.html

but if you refresh the page in Chrome or Firefox the gif doesn't play again.

My code is:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hollywood vs the Great Outdoors</title>

<style>
#case_1 {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:50;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="case_1"><img src="dvd_open_1.gif" /></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help?
Kind regards
Greg

Comment: Works on my end, so you should be good to go :).

Answer (score 7):

The reason why this happens is that the browser is caching the image..sort of.

```
<div id="case_1"><img id="image" src="dvd_open_1.gif" /></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#image").attr("src", "dvd_open_1.gif?" + Math.random());
    });
</script>
```

Basically what this does is adding a random string ?randomNumberString which tricks the browser in thinking that it is different file.

p.s. you will need to include the jQuery lib into your file to use the jQuery(document).ready function.

Comment: This also forces the browser to download the entire image again - and if it's a big image (both bytes and visually), as in the example, there might be user-visible glitches (unloaded image, perceived "frame jumping").

Comment: That's correct. That is why for such (big) animations he should go for Adobe Flash or something alike.